# RxJS: ES6 Array every() equivalent to check each item in an array of Observable booleans

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have an array of 'roles' and need to check if the user has each of these roles. The function to check this, returns an Observable:

```
let roles: string[] = ['role1', 'role2']

public userHasRole(role: string): Observable<boolean> {<already implemented>}
```

I need to return an `Observable<boolean>` or a `Promise<boolean>` which indicates whether or not the user owns each role.

I can solve this with Promises:

```
let promises: Promise<boolean>[] = roles.map(r => this.auth.currentUserHasRole(r).toPromise());
return Promise.all(promises).then(results => results.every(x => x));
```

but I'm assuming there is a more elegant solution with RxJS? I'm using rxjs 6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
public userHasRoles(roles: string[]): Observable<boolean> {

    return from(roles).pipe(
        mergeMap((role) => this.auth.currentUserHasRole(role)),
        reduce((hasPrevRoles, hasRole) => hasPrevRoles && hasRole),
    );
}
```

Using the following imports:

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

---

The [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) function first creates an observable that emits the roles in sequence. Then [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) creates a flattened stream of boolean results from calling `currentUserHasRole` for each role emitted. Finally [`reduce`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce) combines all booleans into one boolean that is only true if all of the input booleans were true, analogous to how Array.reduce works.

`reduce` here is similar to forkJoin: it returns an observable that emits once with the combined value as soon as the input observable completes. The returned observable will then itself complete.

Comment: Not really the answer I had in mind, but works nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: on second thought, it is exactly what I was looking for. I was a bit confused because you wrapped the code into a `userHasRoles` function, but it is indeed a great solution.

Comment: Yes, I assumed the method context from `this.auth.currentUserHasRole`. This way it's clearer to other readers where `roles` probably comes from, and what its type is. Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 2):

For RxJS way, Try:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public userHasRoles(roles: string[]): Observable<boolean> {
 return combineLatest(
    // spread the array of observables as a comma list
    ...roles.map(role => this.auth.currentUserHasRole(role)),
  ).pipe(
    map(results => results.every(result => result)),
  );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `forkJoin` be a better fit than `combineLatest`? The docs state that `combineLatest` is suitable for long-running Observables.

Comment: You don't need to spread the array for `forkJoin` or `combineLatest`.

Comment: Oh, maybe that changed with the later API. Okay, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As per your method signature you are taking only one string as an argument, so you can simply use a `findIndex` and `of` operator to convert it into `Observable`

```
public userHasRole(role:string): Observable<boolean>{
     roles.findIndex(i=>i===role)!==-1 ? of(true) : of(false)
}
```

add the import statement

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```